# How can I solve that problem with composer?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, composer-php

Trying to install codecept file with Composer

And I have this

> D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php>composer require
> "codeception/codeception:*" ./composer.json has been updated Loading
> composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies
> (including require-dev) Nothing to install or update Generating
> autoload files 31 packages you are using are looking for funding. Use
> the composer fund command to find out more!
>
> @php requirements.php
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
> denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
> D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:705
> Stack trace:
> #0 D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(705):
> PDO->__construct()
> #1 D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(626):
> yii\db\Connection->createPdoInstance()
> #2 D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(1022):
> yii\db\Connection->open()
> #3 D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(1009):
> yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()
> #4 D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php(696):
> yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()
> #5 D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(994):
> yii\db\Schema->getServerVersion()
> #6 D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php\requirements.php(67): yii\db\Connection->getServerVersion()
> #7 {main}
>
> Next yii\db\Exception: in
> D:\OpenServer\domains\opensource.php\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php
> on line 637 Script @php requirements.php handling the post-update-cmd
> event returned with error code 255

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

**This is my requirements.php file**

```
<?php
/**
 * Application requirement checker script.
 *
 * In order to run this script use the following console command:
 * php requirements.php
 *
 * In order to run this script from the web, you should copy it to the web root.
 * If you are using Linux you can create a hard link instead, using the following command:
 * ln ../requirements.php requirements.php
 */

// you may need to adjust this path to the correct Yii framework path
// uncomment and adjust the following line if Yii is not located at the default path
//$frameworkPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2';


if (!isset($frameworkPath)) {
    $searchPaths = array(
        dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2',
        dirname(__FILE__) . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2',
    );
    foreach ($searchPaths as $path) {
        if (is_dir($path)) {
            $frameworkPath = $path;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (!isset($frameworkPath) || !is_dir($frameworkPath)) {
    $message = "<h1>Error</h1>\n\n"
        . "<p><strong>The path to yii framework seems to be incorrect.</strong></p>\n"
        . '<p>You need to install Yii framework via composer or adjust the framework path in file <abbr title="' . __FILE__ . '">' . basename(__FILE__) . "</abbr>.</p>\n"
        . '<p>Please refer to the <abbr title="' . dirname(__FILE__) . "/README.md\">README</abbr> on how to install Yii.</p>\n";

    if (!empty($_SERVER['argv'])) {
        // do not print HTML when used in console mode
        echo strip_tags($message);
    } else {
        echo $message;
    }
    exit(1);
}

require_once($frameworkPath . '/requirements/YiiRequirementChecker.php');
$requirementsChecker = new YiiRequirementChecker();

$gdMemo = $imagickMemo = 'Either GD PHP extension with FreeType support or ImageMagick PHP extension with PNG support is required for image CAPTCHA.';
$gdOK = $imagickOK = false;

if (extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    $imagick = new Imagick();
    $imagickFormats = $imagick->queryFormats('PNG');
    if (in_array('PNG', $imagickFormats)) {
        $imagickOK = true;
    } else {
        $imagickMemo = 'Imagick extension should be installed with PNG support in order to be used for image CAPTCHA.';
    }
}

if (extension_loaded('gd')) {
    $gdInfo = gd_info();
    if (!empty($gdInfo['FreeType Support'])) {
        $gdOK = true;
    } else {
        $gdMemo = 'GD extension should be installed with FreeType support in order to be used for image CAPTCHA.';
    }
}

/**
 * Adjust requirements according to your application specifics.
 */
$requirements = array(
    // Database :
    array(
        'name' => 'PDO extension',
        'mandatory' => true,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo'),
        'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'PDO SQLite extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo_sqlite'),
        'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
        'memo' => 'Required for SQLite database.',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'PDO MySQL extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql'),
        'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
        'memo' => 'Required for MySQL database.',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'PDO PostgreSQL extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo_pgsql'),
        'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
        'memo' => 'Required for PostgreSQL database.',
    ),
    // Cache :
    array(
        'name' => 'Memcache extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('memcache') || extension_loaded('memcached'),
        'by' => '<a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-memcache.html">MemCache</a>',
        'memo' => extension_loaded('memcached') ? 'To use memcached set <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-memcache.html#$useMemcached-detail">MemCache::useMemcached</a> to <code>true</code>.' : ''
    ),
    // CAPTCHA:
    array(
        'name' => 'GD PHP extension with FreeType support',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => $gdOK,
        'by' => '<a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captcha.html">Captcha</a>',
        'memo' => $gdMemo,
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'ImageMagick PHP extension with PNG support',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => $imagickOK,
        'by' => '<a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captcha.html">Captcha</a>',
        'memo' => $imagickMemo,
    ),
    // PHP ini :
    'phpExposePhp' => array(
        'name' => 'Expose PHP',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => $requirementsChecker->checkPhpIniOff("expose_php"),
        'by' => 'Security reasons',
        'memo' => '"expose_php" should be disabled at php.ini',
    ),
    'phpAllowUrlInclude' => array(
        'name' => 'PHP allow url include',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => $requirementsChecker->checkPhpIniOff("allow_url_include"),
        'by' => 'Security reasons',
        'memo' => '"allow_url_include" should be disabled at php.ini',
    ),
    'phpSmtp' => array(
        'name' => 'PHP mail SMTP',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => strlen(ini_get('SMTP')) > 0,
        'by' => 'Email sending',
        'memo' => 'PHP mail SMTP server required',
    ),
);

// OPcache check
if (!version_compare(phpversion(), '5.5', '>=')) {
    $requirements[] = array(
        'name' => 'APC extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('apc'),
        'by' => '<a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-apccache.html">ApcCache</a>',
    );
}

$result = $requirementsChecker->checkYii()->check($requirements)->getResult();
$requirementsChecker->render();
exit($result['summary']['errors'] === 0 ? 0 : 1);
```

**And this is composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "opensourcewebsite/core",
    "description": "OpenSourceWebsite Core",
    "keywords": [
        "opensourcewebsite",
        "osw",
        "yii2",
        "yii",
        "php7",
        "php"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://opensourcewebsite.org",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/opensourcewebsite-org/opensourcewebsite-org/issues?state=open",
        "source": "https://github.com/opensourcewebsite-org/opensourcewebsite-org"
    },
    "funding": [
        {
            "type": "opencollective",
            "url": "https://opencollective.com/opensourcewebsite"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4",
        "ext-bcmath": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-PDO": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.35",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "^2.0",
        "almasaeed2010/adminlte": "^3.0",
        "cebe/yii2-gravatar": "^1.1",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.5",
        "brussens/yii2-maintenance-mode": "^0.2",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "^2.1",
        "npm-asset/ace-builds": "^1.4.1",
        "yiisoft/yii2-httpclient": "^2.0.0",
        "telegram-bot/api": "^2.3",
        "longman/telegram-bot": "^0.61",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "^1.4",
        "janisto/yii2-timepicker": "^1.1",
        "ivankff/yii2-modal-ajax": "^4.1",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "^2.0",
        "yii2tech/ar-position": "^1.0",
        "voskobovich/yii2-linker-behavior": "^4.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "^2.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "^2.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "^2.0",
        "codeception/codeception": "^4.0",
        "codeception/module-asserts": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-filesystem": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-yii2": "^1.0",
        "codeception/specify": "^1.3",
        "codeception/verify": "^1.3",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.16"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.4"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php requirements.php"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postInstall",
            "@php requirements.php"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postInstall": {
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web-local.php"
            ],
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "runtime/cache": "0777",
                    "runtime/debug": "0777",
                    "runtime/logs": "0777",
                    "runtime/mail": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me with this problem

Comment: Looks like it's executing a PHP file called `requirements.php`, which makes some database connection with invalid credentials.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson
Thanks a lot for such a quick response.
I have this in my requirements.php file about mysql:
array(
        'name' => 'PDO MySQL extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql'),
        'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
        'memo' => 'Required for MySQL database.',
    )

Comment: Please show us both your composer.json and your requirements.php file. Also, have you configured yii with the correct database credentials?

Comment: What's your question about this? Looks like your database credentials are wrong - how is this related to Composer?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson 
Yes, I have
I show both files

Comment: @NicoHaase
All my website work is alright
But when I use Composer I saw that

Comment: I ask again: have you configured yii with the correct database credentials? In your composer file, you have some scripts that runs on composer install/update. One of those scripts are trying to connect to the database using wrong credentials. You need to check your configuration. I don't really see what else we can to here.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have configured yii with the correct db credentials, but maybe I didn't do this in the file that the composer requires, can you tell me which file should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get answer for that question. The problem was in correct db credentials